# Creating a library with Typescript - exporting and .d.ts declarations

Tags: typescript

I see in the docs that I could use a `.d.ts` file to declare exports, say

```
export default function getArrayLength(arr: any[]): number;
```

But this seems redundant when I have already written the functions in a `.ts` file with the type expectations

```
export default function getArrayLength(arr: any[]): number {
  return 42;
}
```

Is there a way to simply export already defined functions as they are in the `.ts` files? I'm assuming I need to do the `.d.ts` file right now because when trying to import, the IDE doesn't auto suggest what I could import.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a library into a Typescript library when you have

```
Library
  /src
    /Function
       --functions.ts
    --index.js
```

will not allow TS to determine the type definitions automatically. Instead, use an `index.d.ts` to replace the `index.js`, which can export all other files with

```
// index.d.ts

export * from /Function/functions.ts
```

This will allow VS Code to pick up on exported members and type definitions automatically.